# How do you edit tab labels per tab in GVim?

Tags: editor, vim

How do you edit a tab label, per tab, in GVim?

You can do this:

```
set guitablabel=foo
```

But that will set every tab's label to "foo".

The documentation seems to suggest using a t:var, like this:

```
let t:guitablabel="foo"
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Is there any way to give each different tab a different name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename tabs in VIM:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1678